# How many ways are there to distribute 18 different toys among four children? Without restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My thought process was

Okay use $C(4+18-1, 4) = 5985$

But the book I'm using says it's $4^{18}$

How come it's $4^{18}$?

Comment: Each toy can go independently to any of the $4$ children.  Note:  Stars and Bars assumes that the toys are indistinguishable  which is not the case here.

Comment: Just so you'll know, If it had been stars and bars, it would have been $$\binom{18 + [4-1]}{[4-1]} = \binom{21}{3}.$$

Comment: Yes, Thank You. I now see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the $18$ toys has one of four recipients. Assuming all toys must be distributed, we have $4^{18}$ as desired.